# type mismatch; found : edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap => Unit required: java.util.function.Consumer[_ >: edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap]

Tags: scala

I don't understand what it wants from me. The assignment to `sentence` is working:

```
val sentences : java.util.List[CoreMap] = document.get(classOf[SentencesAnnotation])
```

but I can't run a `forEach` loop on this:

```
sentences.forEach( (s : CoreMap) => println("") )
```

since I am getting:

```
Error:(39, 38) type mismatch; found   : edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap => Unit required: java.util.function.Consumer[_ >: edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap]
sentences.forEach( (s : CoreMap) => println("") )
             ^
```

What is the problem here? `s` has a type given already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using **Java's** `forEach` (which indeed expects a `java.util.function.Consumer`), did you mean Scala's `foreach`? `foreach` would work (if you import `JavaConversions`):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
sentences.foreach( (s : CoreMap) => println("") )
```

Comment: Thanks! I already imported `scala.collection.JavaConversions._` but used `forEach` instead of `foreach`. My mistake! :)

Comment: Any idea why `for( s : CoreMap <- sentences) { /* .. */ }` then throws an exception? ^^

Comment: @displayname You should define your `sentences` as `List` (which is `scala.collection.immutable.List`, rather than `java.util.List`. If you do this, all the problems will go away.

Comment: Although your solution looks much simpler (+1), you could also use `forEach` with an anonymous class `sentences.forEach(new java.util.function.Consumer[CoreMap] { def accept(cm: CoreMap) = println(cm) })`

Comment: @displayname can't really help you with that other exception - that's a different question, with not enough details (what exception, sample data..). If this solved the original issue, feel free to accept ;)

Comment: it appears this exception comes from IntelliJ and Scala version clash or something